# Is there any way to fix size of custom dropdown arrow in css?

Tags: css

I am trying to fix the custom dropdown arrow size but when i zoom in or zoom out webpage size of custom dropdown also changed.. Is there any solution for that??

This is current web page

[image]

When I zoom in or zoom out custom arrow size will be changed..

[image]

Here is my code :-

```css
.container select {
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px 38px 7px 23px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  appearance: none;
  position: relative;
}

.container i.fa-angle-down {
  position: absolute;
  right: 69%;
  top: 92.5%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 8px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h6>Current open positions</h6>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="search">Search by Location</label>
    <select>
      <option>Canada</option>
      <option>USA</option>
    </select><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can we see you html please

Comment: @Gad I added html code...

Comment: Your issue lies with the arrow being set to "position: absolute". With this set the position of the arrow will always be positioned to wherever it is set for.  If you want to make it move with the select container, you need to make it relative to that container.

Comment: @StrayAnt I tried to change absolute to relative but it's not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supply a relative container to act as a boundary for the absolute positioned child. Something like below, cheers;

```css
.container select {
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px 38px 7px 23px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  appearance: none;
  position: relative;
}

.container i.fa-angle-down {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1rem;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 8px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.custom-dd {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <h6>Current open positions</h6>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="search">Search by Location</label>
    <div class="custom-dd">
      <select>
        <option>Canada</option>
        <option>USA</option>
      </select>
      <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```